# MapInfo Error - 'Invalid distance units: .'

Tags: mapinfo

I am receiving an error (`Invalid distance units`) when attempting to import a MapInfo MIF File (.mif) into MapInfo.

[image]

Has anyone come across this error before?

Can't seem to find much about in the MapInfo documentation or online.

Opening a similar file in Notepad, where I get the same error, shows the following:

[image]

Comment: What are your distance units, and what is the projection?

Comment: Hi, the projection is OSGB36 and I think the distance units are kilometres.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 1):

In the MIF file where you have the line specifying the coordinate system, the distance unit has two pairs of quotation marks around it, e.g.`""m""` . Remove one of the pairs of quotations so that you only have one left, e.g. `"m"`, and save the file. It should now import ok.